# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'. Exception while doing past iteration backup

Tags: android, android-studio

I got this error while compiling one of my android project in android studio 2.0. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project.
2. Try to build. If not solved, do following stuff

Add multidex support to your application. If application class is exist in your application then add attachBaseContext method otherwise create one and register in menifest.xml,under name attribute of application tag.

```
 public class YouApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }

    }
```

And update your build.gradle(app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Build -> Rebuild Project  and then Run again.
or
Build -> Clean Project

or both of them